# Internet Explorer removes Blockquote styling

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having real issues with blockquotes in IE, IE disables ignores any styling leaving just plain text.  Hoping anyone knows a solution :D

The code is:

```
.testimonial 
{
margin: 0;
background: #0054a4;
padding: 15px 50px;
position: relative;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
color: #fff001;
font-style: italic;
font-size:20px;
line-height:20px;
}

.testimonial:before, .testimonial:after 
{
content: "\201C";
position: absolute;
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 1;
color: #fff001;
font-style: normal;
}

.testimonial:before 
{
top: 0;
left: 10px;
}

.testimonial:after 
{
content: "\201D";
right: 10px;
bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

Comment: tested with ie 11 and works perfectly fine.

Comment: tested in IE11, IE10 compability, IE9. Block quoted is styled correctly everywhere. ctrl+f5. There are undefined js varaibles in the console tho.

Comment: @Escobear Just curious. How can you get undefined js variables from a piece of css?

Comment: he posted a link to the original site and deleted the comment.